# Azure ability to resolve query based alert automatically

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, alerts

I want to resolve query based alert automatically if condition don't meet or with by a "good" result.  is there any alternative way to resolve custom log search alerts . I checked these links and not possible to do that

- https://feedback.azure.com/forums/602299-azure-monitor-alert-management/suggestions/39989395-add-ability-to-resolve-query-based-alert
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/alerts/alerts-unified-log
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/43802/alerts-generated-in-azure-alerts-are-in-fired-stat.html

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no. Currently, it is not supported, and no other workarounds.

You can upvote the user feedback.